# issue with ajax combox control

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

i am using ajax     combo box  control. Here i have  items
like

- kiran
         james
         alice
         dinesh
         prakash
         manu

if user  type  the  word like  "kushal" as this  word   is  not there   in the  items  of the    control    this  word   should not  be  set in  combo box  control.  but  if the  word is there    in     controls  it  should  be  allowed  to  set in the  control

hope  my  Question is  clear.
  thank  you

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question, is this what you mean?

```
<input id="name" type="text" onkeyup="selectItem(this.value)" />
<select id="combo">
    <option>kiran</option>
    <option>james</option>
    <option>alice</option>
    <option>dinesh</option>
    <option>prakash</option>
    <option>manu</option>
</select>
<script>
  function selectItem(name){
     var combo = document.getElementById('combo');
     for(var i=0;i<combo.options.length;i++){
        if(combo.options[i].text == name){
           combo.options[i].selected = true;
           combo.selectedIndex = i;
           combo.value = name;
        }
     }
  }
</script>
```

or the shorter version:

```
 <input id="name" type="text" onkeyup="document.getElementById('combo').value=this.name;" />
```